# Numpy warning when trying to assign NaN

Tags: numpy, nan

```
import numpy as np
import random

aa = np.random.rand(20,20)
aa[aa<0.5] = np.NaN
aa[aa>0.8] = np.NaN
```

I get the warning at the last line of code:
`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater`

Is this a legit warning? How to fix/avoid it?

Comment: When you do `aa>0.8`, `aa` has a bunch of NaNs in it. You're trying to compare those NaNs to 0.8.

Comment: thanks @user2357112, how can I avoid/fix the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my version the 2 maskings run fine:

```
In [388]: aa = np.random.rand(20,20)
In [389]: aa[aa<0.5]=np.NaN
In [390]: np.isnan(aa).sum()
Out[390]: 203
In [391]: aa[aa>0.8]=np.NaN
In [392]: np.isnan(aa).sum()
Out[392]: 279
In [393]: np.__version__
Out[393]: '1.11.2'
In [394]:
```

But if it did give an error, I can bypass it by creating one mask, and applying it once:

```
In [394]: aa = np.random.rand(20,20)
In [395]: mask = (aa<0.5)|(aa>0.8)
In [396]: aa[mask]=np.nan
In [397]: np.isnan(aa).sum()
Out[397]: 280
```

Comment: thanks, i do have same numpy version as you so not sure why you dont get same warning as me

Comment: I think you probably already got the warning once in that session, so it didn't come up again when you ran the test. 387 lines of input before this is a lot of time to forget about a warning.

Comment: I tried it in a new `ipython` session, and still no warning.  I'm running Python3, so that may make a difference.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe that is it I am on python 2.7.12 and pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to replace the values less than the threshold with np.NaN?  If so, then you can use this amongst other options.

```
import random
a = np.random.rand(5,5)*10
b = np.where(a < 5, np.NaN, a)
[[ 2.334  5.423  4.093  5.061  4.724]
 [ 0.565  0.549  1.228  5.686  5.660]
 [ 0.235  2.560  3.253  9.910  4.977]
 [ 2.750  4.553  8.291  4.013  6.825]
 [ 8.261  9.474  6.319  8.630  5.207]]
[[ nan  5.423  nan  5.061  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  5.686  5.660]
 [ nan  nan  nan  9.910  nan]
 [ nan  nan  8.291  nan  6.825]
 [ 8.261  9.474  6.319  8.630  5.207]]
```